# defining an operator "distance" instead of the operator "in" with python sets

Tags: python

If I save the (x,y,z) coordinates of some points in a python set ('coord') I can check very easily if a point belongs to the set doing

```
(X,Y,Z) in coord
```

but if my coordinates are real numbers I have to have the exact real number for a match.

```
F = (0.0, 1.1, 2.0)
coordinates.add(F)
G = (0.0, 1.100000000001, 2.0)
G in coordinates
False
```

Is there a way to define an 'in' operator that use a distance criteria instead of an equality criteria? Because I would know how to do this with a for cycle but the in operator is so fast...

Comment: "Because I would know how to do this with a for cycle but the in operator is so fast" - `in` with sets is based on a hash table lookup, which won't work for looking up nearby points. A set is probably not an appropriate data structure, if this is what you want to do with it.

Comment: `in` being fast depends what you use it on; you can implement `__contains__` for the *syntax*, but it will probably still have the same loop inside.

Comment: You will most likely want to go with writing a function to determine if the point is in the coordinates, such as `isXinY = lambda x, y: any([((x[0]-i[0])**2+(x[1]-i[1])**2+(x[2]-i[2])**2)**0.5 < <max_distance> for i in y])`

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that fairly easy.

Use vector logic to compare two points:

```
def fuzzy_eq(A, B):
    EPS = 0.01

    # first, find a delta between two points
    x = A[0] - B[0]
    y = A[1] - B[1]
    z = A[2] - B[2]

    # next, find the length of that delta
    length = sqrt(x*x + y*y + z*z)

    # finally, check the length
    return length < EPS:
```

But it'll be a lot easier with some 3D vector library:

```
def fuzzy_eq(A, B):
    EPS = 0.01

    # assuming A and B are of some 3D vector class
    length = (A-B).length()
    return length < EPS
```

Implement your own function instead of `in` operator:

```
def fuzzy_in(coords, X):
    return any(fuzzy_eq(coord, X) for coord in coords)

fuzzy_in(coordinates, G)
```

To use `in` operator your way, your should subclass set (or other similar container) and override the `__contains__` method:

```
class Coordinates(set):

    def __contains__(self, value):
        return fuzzy_in(self, value)
```

Also, as @user2357112 pointed out, you probably don't need a set for this case.

And if your goal is speed, and you **already** have issues with it, you should use some other language. Or some fast library that uses C, for example, that will do the slow part.